# get JSON doesnt work for me

Tags: php, jquery, json

I made php file that parse JSON object. here's an example of result from the php:

```
{"ID":"951","NameOfEvent":"\u05dc\u05d9\u05d9\u05df \u05d4\u05e7\u05e8\u05d9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d9 \u05d1\u05e9\u05dc\u05d9\u05e9\u05d9","Plan":"\u05d4\u05d2\u05d5\u05e8\u05df - \u05dc\u05d9\u05d9\u05df \u05d4\u05e7\u05e8\u05d9\u05d5\u05e7\u05d9 \u05d1\u05e9\u05dc\u05d9\u05e9\u05d9 @ \u05d4\u05d2\u05d5\u05e8\u05df.\r\n\r\n\u05de\u05d5\u05e2\u05d3\u05d5\u05df \u05d4\u05d2\u05d5\u05e8\u05df \u05e9\u05d5\u05db\u05df \u05d1\u05e7\u05d9\u05d1\u05d5\u05e5 \u05de\u05e8\u05d7\u05d1\u05d9\u05d4 \u05e9\u05d1\u05e2\u05de\u05e7 \u05d9\u05d6\u05e8\u05e2\u05d0\u05dc.","Avg":"0","Views":"23"}
```

I tried to get the data using the following jquery code:

```
function gettopevents()
{
$.getJSON("jsontopevents.php", function(json) {
    alert(json.NameOfEvent);
});
}
```

I call the function by using button with onclick event.

I dont get whats wrong with my function... I am using the same function to read data from facebook graph and it works..

edit: Wierd thing - it works in IE but not in FF and Chrome

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with a simpler value for 'NameOfEvent'?

Comment: I also tried to alert the ID which is number but it didnt work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've quoted works: http://jsbin.com/iwumu4 Tried it in IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome 9, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5, and Opera 11 on Windows; and Chrome 9, Firefox 3.6, and Opera 11 on Linux.

This suggests the problem lies elsewhere in the code. Your best bet is to use a debugger. Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE8 all have built-in debuggers. You can get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, and VS.Net will debug JavaScript on IE6 and IE7. In the debugger, look at the console as a first thing, to see if any errors are reported. If there aren't, set a breakpoint on the `$.getJSON` call and also the `alert`, and examine the data.

**Update**: *(After your note below.)* Ah, sounds like a caching problem. I should have thought of that. Since `getJSON` uses `GET`, caching is definitely something you have to watch for.

`getJSON` is just a wrapper for [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so you could use

```
$.ajax({
    url:      "jsontopevents.php",
    cache:    false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(json) {
        alert(json.NameOfEvent);
    }
});
```

Note the `cache` argument. See the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs for details.

Comment: aff I hate it, all I had to do is delete the history and cookies. thats lame. Anyway thank you and if I'll need debugger in the future, I'll sure use your solution.

Comment: Even just the standard FF javascript console (shift-ctrl-J) can be of use - it'll log all the JS/css/internal errors encountered.

Comment: @Ron: Ah, interesting. I bet it was caching. Glad you sorted it out. If it *was* a caching problem, updated the answer to talk about how to deal with that...

Comment: Nice to know it Marc B. T.J thank you for you explanation, I belive I should use the ajax method so it'll force requested pages not to be cached. BTW the datatype should be jsonp or json?

Comment: @Ron: If you're returning what you've quoted, the dataType should be "json". [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is different (in JSONP, you're basically returning script code that calls a function named in the request).

Comment: @T.J Crowder, now I understand. Thank you.